# Angular ui-grid can not copy cell text

Tags: angularjs, css, angular-ui-grid

I have an ui-grid where I want to select row by clicking any where on any row.
I also want to copy a cell content to clip board.
I did the following code, but while **enableFullRowSelection** is **true**, I can not select cell content by mouse draging.

Please see the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/3Uc2NsGBTqglYuKki2sn?p=preview). After further investigating I found .ui-grid-disable-selection class is being added to my grid.

So can any one suggest how to solve this?

**EDIT**: If I change **enableFullRowSelection** to **false**, I can select the content.

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ui.grid', 'ui.grid.selection']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
  $scope.data = [
    {a:'A', b:'B'},
    {a:'A1', b:'B1'},
    {a:'A2', b:'B2'},
    {a:'A3', b:'B3'},
    {a:'A4', b:'B4'}
    ];
  $scope.gridOptions = {
 data : 'data',
 enableRowSelection: true,
 enableFullRowSelection: true,
 enableHighlighting : true,
 multiSelect: false
  };
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/angular-ui/bower-ui-grid/master/ui-grid.min.css" type="text/css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.7/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.7"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/angular-ui/bower-ui-grid/master/ui-grid.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <p>Hello {{name}}!</p>
    
    <div style="height:200px" 
    data-ui-grid="gridOptions"
    data-ui-grid-selection></div>
    
  </body>

</html>
```

Please help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think the easiest way is to just override the css class. If you check the ui-grid code then **ui-grid-disable-selection** class is added if both the flags are set

[image: ui-grid-disable-selection]

You can add a class to the grid element as shown below

```
    <div style="height:200px"
    class="ui-grid-selectable"
    data-ui-grid="gridOptions"
    data-ui-grid-selection></div>

    .ui-grid-selectable .ui-grid-disable-selection {
         -webkit-touch-callout: default;
         -webkit-user-select: text;
         -khtml-user-select: text;
         -moz-user-select: text;
         -ms-user-select: text;
         user-select: text;
         cursor:auto;
     }
```

Check the updated [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/MnBoTv4iYWGReAxcgqYR?p=preview).

Comment: HI All, what if we want to copy the whole selected row without dragging the mouse and using Ctrl+C ? Is there any way or trick? I have the similar requirement as below: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57520588/copy-the-row-data-on-clipboard-on-select-of-a-row-in-angular-ui-grid