# How to enable text selection in angular ui grid with row selection enabled

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I am using ui-grid v3.1.1 and have enabled rowSelection. I notice that when I enable row selection, I can no longer select (click-hold-drag) text from  the rows.

I noticed the same behaviour in the [example](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/210_selection) in their tutorials (second grid on the page).

It would be great to know if there is some work around by which I can still allow the user to select text, while the rowSelection is enabled.

[Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/DTqwE9Apkg29XWf6r0EO?p=preview) is a plunkr link to the example from the tutorial.

```
$scope.gridOptions = { 
     enableRowSelection: true, 
     enableRowHeaderSelection: false 
};
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A [previous SO answer by @Aman Mahajan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33912587/angular-ui-grid-can-not-copy-cell-text) offers a fix:

A `ui-grid-disable-selection` class is added to the grid when both `enableRowSelection` and `enableFullRowSelection`are enabled (can check [ui-grid  v3.1.1 source in selection.js](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-grid/blob/68681d71823fc0c1b9f45e9fa7832de71233c7ab/src/features/selection/js/selection.js) ~line 903). So you can override the CSS class by adding a specific class to your grid, for example `ui-grid-selectable`.

```
<div ui-grid="gridOptions" ui-grid-selection class="grid ui-grid-selectable"></div>
```

And in your CSS:

```
.ui-grid-selectable .ui-grid-disable-selection {
     -webkit-touch-callout: default;
     -webkit-user-select: text;
     -khtml-user-select: text;
     -moz-user-select: text;
     -ms-user-select: text;
     user-select: text;
     cursor:auto;
 }
```

Here's [the forked plunker with the added CSS class](http://plnkr.co/edit/TMRc9xWjudJTgOEmzFyx?p=preview) to override the default behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I definitely like [BennettAdams](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4586573/bennett-adams) answer better, but just in case anyone needs another way to do it, you can add `ui-grid-edit` to your html grid tag like so:

```
<div ui-grid="gridOptions" ui-grid-selection ui-grid-edit></div>
```

Note: this also requires defining `ui.grid.edit` in your app definition like so:

```
var app = angular.module('myGridApp', ['ui.grid', 'ui.grid.edit'])
```

**Cons:**

- Requires you to double-click the cell to get to the text
- Allows users to edit the cell value *(although the changes will not be saved if it's not set up)*

**Pros:**

- Double-clicking cell automatically highlights all the text
- More readable code *(although it may not be obvious why the cell is editable if no changes are persisted)*.