# Copy the row data on clipboard on select of a row in Angular UI-Grid

Tags: css, angularjs, angular-ui-grid, ui-grid

I have the requirement of copying the whole row data on clipboard on just select/click of a row. I'm sharing the plunker URL where I'm only able to copy the cell text -

http://plnkr.co/edit/EVrB5Ib9ZuqhbAMsV9Eg?p=preview

Pseduo Code for Grid Options is as below-

```
        *$scope.gridOptions = {
            data : 'data',
            enableRowSelection: true,
            enableFullRowSelection: true,
            enableHighlighting : true,
            multiSelect: false,
            enableRowHeaderSelection: false
        };*
```

Say, If i click on second row, both 'A1' and 'B1' should get copied and the same can be pasted over some notepad or any other app.

[image]

Comment: Looks like UI-Grid doesn't support this functionality directly. Any other trick or workaround please ?

Answer (score 0):

This requires several steps I think: first, you would have to register the rowSelectionChanged eventhandler, to capture any changes in selection. Something like:

```
$scope.gridOptions.onRegisterApi = function(gridApi) {
  $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
  gridApi.selection.on.rowSelectionChanged($scope,function(row){
    if(row.isSelected) {
      // copy row.entity data to clipboard
    }
  });
}
```

Addressing the clipboard from AnularJS I have not done before. It seems [this package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-clipboard) might be what you're looking for, but there may be different solutions.